# exclude xml files of test-classes folder

Tags: java, xml, spring, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I am loading all xml file in my project with particular path.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.xml" });
```

My Project includes various jars .

These jars have `META-INF/spring/*.xml` files in test-classes folder.

i.e. xml files in test cases of internal jars.

Can I configure a path such that I can exclude xml files of test case projects and only include xml files of src/main project.

Please help